# TypeError: a is undefined in json fill jqgrid

Tags: jquery, json

> TypeError: a is undefined

in

```
 newStr = "{total:" + '"' + 1 + '"' + "," + "page:" + '"' + 1 + '"' + ","
 + "records:" + '"'
 + resultCount + '"' + ","
 + "rows:"
 + "[" + dataFromList + "]}";
 alert(newStr );
 var a = jQuery("#list")[0];
 a.addJSONData(newStr);
```

Comment: did you declare a ? seems you did not.

Comment: am declared a just c my code. am declared as var a= jQuery("#list")[0];

Answer (score 1):

There is no element found with the id 'list', so `jQuery("#list")` returns `[ ]`, and then `jQuery("#list")[0]` returns `undefined`.  The error is thrown on the next line when you try to call the `addJSONData` method of `undefined`.